# variable not defined in tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

i don't understand my problem.. tkinter keeps telling me that variables are not defined..
this is the error:

```
secondi_rec is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)
minuti_rec is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)
```

and here's my code:

```
minutes_rec = int("0")
seconds_rec = int("0")
time_rec = (str(minutes_rec)+":"+str(seconds_rec))

label_recording = tk.Button(window, text="Recording...  "+time_rec)
label_recording.after(1000, updater)

def updater():
    if seconds_rec > 59:
        minutes_rec = str(minutes_rec+1)
    else:
        if seconds_rec < 9:
            seconds_rec = str(0+str(seconds_rec+1))
        else:
            seconds_rec = str(seconds_rec+1)

    time_rec = (str(minutes_rec)+":"+str(seconds_rec))
```

Comment: Hello, I'm not exactly sure as to where the problem is, as this code extract provided doesn't contain any reference to those elements specified."secondi_rec" and the other. If you could provide a sample around the usage of those variables or state that there is no usage of those variables, that would help. Thanks!

Comment: The code in your question makes no sense with respect to tkinter (or otherwise for that matter). You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: What is pylance? Is it a module? I have only heard of a vscode extension with that name.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no variable named `secondi_rec` or `minuti_rec` is defined in your code, anywhere, nor are you referencing it. As mentioned by @martineau in the comments, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Second, the `updater()` function is called before it is defined.